# disable mouse event on 1st and re-enable the same on 3rd click - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick, mouseevent

I have a div which changes colors on multiple onclick events.

```
var linkClick = 1; 
  function update_link(obj){ 
  if (linkClick == 1){obj.style.border = 'solid 1px red'};
  if (linkClick == 2){obj.style.border = 'solid 1px blue'};
  if (linkClick == 3){obj.style.border = 'solid 1px green'};
  if (linkClick >3 ) {obj.style.border = 'solid 1px #555555'; linkClick=0};
  linkClick++; 
}
```

and in html: `onclick="update_link(this);"`

I need onmouseenter and onmouseleave to be disabled when I click the 1st time, and to be re-enabled again when I click the 3rd time.

I've tried to put `this.onmouseleave='null'` in `onclick` but I don't know how to re-enable it with another click or event.

Does somebody knows how to achieve this?

Comment: The events are probably firing too quickly to be differentiated. I have some code in c# that deals with a similar issue, using timers. I can toss it up for you if you think it might help.  I'm pretty sure Javascript has some type of timer class.

Comment: thanks but I don't think this is the problem in this case. even with basic mouse events, without this function, I can't re-enable the event. Maybe because I don't know the right opposite from null (tried 1, true and enabled - doesn't work...)

Comment: Have you tried changing `null` to `false`?